# What is the right way of storing screen-scraping data?

Tags: database-design, screen-scraping, web-scraping, store, datastore

i'm working on a web site. it is scraping product details(names, features, prices etc.) from various web sites, processing and displaying them. i'am considering to run update script on each day and keep data fresh.

1. scrape data
2. process them
3. store on database
4. read(from db) and display them

i'am already storing all the data in a sql schema but i'm not sure. After each update, all the old records are vanishing. if the scraped new data comes corrupted somehow, there is nothing to show.

so, is there any common way to archive the old data? which one is more convenient: seperate sql schemas or xml files? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend putting the data into a MySQL database. 
There will be loads of examples out there on how to do it securely and you can control your data from their for past scrapes and just display the latest data at the same time it is added.

Go to the source: http://php.about.com/od/security/Security_for_PHP_and_MySQL.htm